# Extract coordinates of polygons centroids

Tags: r, polygon, raster

I’d like to add the latitude and the longitude of all polygons’ centroids to the dataframe of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. However, since I’m not sure how to extract the polygons id when using  gCentroid, I’m not sure how to do the merge (see 3rd line of code below). Is someone able to help me with this? Thanks a lot!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rgeos)
ETH <- getData("GADM", country = "ETH", level = 3) # example of SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
cent <- as.data.frame(gCentroid(ETH, byid=TRUE)) # extraction of the coordinates of the polygons' centroids
ETH@data <- ETH@data %>% left_join(cent, by=?) # Here, I am not sure how to add the coordinates of the polygons' centroids to the dataframe.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `id =`  parameter in `gCentroid` to choose the ID labels for each point. Select a column with unique entries from `ETH` to populate this. These get added as row names, so you can then use `tibble::rownames_to_column` to convert these to a column. This allows the left join:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rgeos)

ETH      <- getData("GADM", country = "ETH", level = 3) 
cent     <- as.data.frame(gCentroid(ETH, byid = TRUE, id = ETH@data$GID_3))
cent     <- tibble::rownames_to_column(cent, var = "GID_3")
ETH@data <- ETH@data %>% left_join(cent, by = "GID_3")
```

And we can show this by plotting the result, with the centroids as red points:

```r
plot(ETH)
points(ETH@data$x, ETH@data$y, col = "red")
```

[image]